# Google maps for Rails: after map load callback

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

How can I add a callback function to the infowindow in Gmaps for Rails? I need to write an Ajax/JSON function for buttons *inside* that window.

Searching hasn't gotten me very far. Any help?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({
    provider: {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    },
    internal: { id: 'map' }
  },
  function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @map_hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    // trying to add this function
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(handler.map, 'idle', function() {
    console.log('map loaded');
    $('.survey-response').click(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      var response = $(this).attr('data-response');
      console.log(id + ' ' + response);
      $.getJSON('/potentials/' + id + '/' + response, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      })
    })
  })
  });
</script>
```

Removing the callback from above (after the comment) and using this code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map, "click", function() {
  alert("You clicked the map.");
});
```

Returns this error:

```
Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own builder to handle the infowindows [as explained there](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Change-handler-behavior#infobox).

This way you can bind your js events as you need.